# Repeat unterminated command every x interval of time

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a command after amount of time. I found these solutions:

```
watch -n60 command

while true; do command; sleep 60; done
```

They are working good if the command terminates (for example: `echo "message"`)

The code which I'm running doesn't terminate. That's why those solutions are not working for me. But I want to run it, terminate it after 60 seconds and run it again. How can I do that?

Comment: And what happens after you run it 1000 times - and none terminates?  You have 1000 processes still running?  You are bound to kill your server/system/whatever.  You should really rethink what you want/need.

Comment: @AleksG I want to terminate and relaunch it after amount of time

Comment: Background the commad: `while true; do command &; sleep 60; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`timeout` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)

```
while true; do timeout 60 command; done
```

Note that if the command exits before the 60 seconds are up, it will re-execute immediately rather than waiting for the minute to be up.

Answer (score 0):

This starts the `command` every 60 seconds and kills the process if it is unterminated:

```
while true; do command &; LAST_PID=$!; sleep 60; kill -9 $LAST_PID; done
```